# How do I display text on button click in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

Have this code (below) and am trying to display the text at the click of a button in React.js.

Heres the code:

```
class App extends Component{

render(){ 
  alert=()=>{return(<h1>Hi</h1>)}
  return(<div className="App">
    <button onClick={this.alert}>Enter</button>
  </div>);

}}

export default App;
```

Any ideas why it's not working...?

Comment: `this` refers to the class `App`. But the `alert` function you declared is inside the `render` method and so it is not a child of `App` class. So `this` won't work here. Remove `this` and try again

Comment: You are returning the rendered function component to onClick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display it in an alert window, you need to call a function to trigger the window.

```
class App extends Component{

  onButtonClickHandler = () => {
    window.alert('Hi')
  };

  render(){ 
    return(<div className="App">
      <button onClick={this.onButtonClickHandler}>Enter</button>
    </div>);

  }
}
```

However, if you need to show the message in your render, you can use a state to manage that.

```
class App extends Component{
  state = {
    showMessage: false
  }
  onButtonClickHandler = () => {
   this.setState({showMessage: true});
  };

  render(){ 
    return(<div className="App">
     {this.state.showMessage && <p>Hi</p>}
      <button onClick={this.onButtonClickHandler}>Enter</button>
    </div>);

  }
}
```

Source code:

[image: Edit dank-bush-edxbl]

If you need to toggle the text on button click, you just need to update the `onButtonClickHandler` function to `this.setState({ showMessage: !this.state.showMessage });`.

Comment: Need the text not in a popup

Answer (score 1):

It won't display as like that. Here you are calling alert function and returning some JSX. How react will know where to render?. Do it like below.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    render: false
}
this.alertHi = this.alertHi.bind(this);
}

alertHi() {
 this.setState({render: !this.state.render});
}

render() {
  return(
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={this.alertHi}>Enter</button>
    {this.state.render && <h1>Hi</h1>}
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z8Lansy5/)